# paste value of cell below if cell below is non blank

Tags: excel, vba

I really need to paste value without the clipboard the cell below the cell where I enter the UDF.

For example with the below code

```
Function macropastec5() As Variant
macropastec5 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H7").Value
End Function
```

if I was to enter into cell `H6` =macropastec5()

so how would I use this in any cell to get the cell below it?

I need someting like

```
 Function macropastec5( the cell I'd enter in excel formula bar  ) As Variant
macropastec5 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(" the cell below where I enter in formula bar").Value
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this function, make sure to input your range in the function. For example if you use the function and input C1 the function will copy value from C2 as I am increasing the row by one. Hope this helps.

```
Public Function CopyBelowCell(rng As Range) As Variant

Dim rw As Long
Dim col As Long

rw = rng.Row
col = rng.Column

CopyBelowCell = Cells(rw + 1, col)

End Function
```